# Using Flex & Bison

Tags: grammar, bison, yacc, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to learn Flex & Bison.  I've read through material, and I understand how it works at a theoretical level.  However, I can't seem to even implement the most basic thing without hitting a mental block. (Note: I haven't taken any compiler courses or anything like that...this is my first exposure to any of this stuff).  I think once I see this super basic thing implemented, I'll be able to move on and understand much more easily.

Basically, all I'm trying to do is write a program that upon seeing `type my_type /// some text` will call my_type's function called "set_text", and set the text to what's after that comment.  Rather, my Bison grammar will call the function `my_type.set_text(some text);`  I realize I could do this easily without using Flex and Bison, but the point is to learn.

I already have the files set up correctly...all I need to implement is the token passing (from Flex) and the action taken (from Bison).

My Flex token passing so far:

```
"\/"{3}               { return COMMENT; }
```

My Bison token grabbing so far

```
%token COMMENT
```

and that's seriously all I can come up with.  I know what else I need...I just can't figure out how to do it.  I know that I need: 
a) to pass type and my_type as something 
b) To come up with a "rule" in Bison to handle this stuff and call the function correct function

Any help?  Am I way off already?

**UPDATE (further thoughts on how to do this):**
Maybe my Bison file should include a rule like

```
commented_variable:                           {($2).set_text($4);}
    IDENTIFIER NAME COMMENT COMMENT_TEXT
```

Thus my Flex file would need to pass it those tokens?  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Also, I apologize if this seems like the wrong forum to post this in.  I couldn't find any sites more suitable.  Let me know if you think another Stack Exchange site would have been a better choice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest some stuffs.
Though it isn't impossible to process `COMMENT` and `COMMENT_TEXT`
individually using start condition of `flex`, I suppose it's easier to
handle them at a time.
`bison` source will be like the following(fictitious code):

```
%union {
  name_type *name;
  char const *comment;
}
%token <name> NAME
%token <comment> COMMENT
%%
commented_variable: IDENTIFIER NAME COMMENT {$2->set_text($3);}
```

From lexical viewpoint, your `IDENTIFIER` and `NAME` seem indistinguishable.
So I sorted them out in user code(not lexically).
`flex` source will be like the following:

```
"///".*                 {
                        yylval.comment = strdup( yytext + 3 );
                        return COMMENT;
                        }
[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*  {
                        name_type *n = lookup_name( yytext );
                        if ( n ) {
                          yylval.name = n;
                          return NAME;
                        }
                        return IDENTIFIER;
                        }
```

However, the above code still needs appropriate `name_type` and
`lookup_name`, and `free`ing the pointer returned from `strdup`.
If you don't have much experience in `flex`/`bison`, I'd recommend first
confirming lexer sufficiently.
For example, I suggest confirming that expected tokens are recognized
with simple code like
`int main() { while ( yylex() ) {} }` and

```
"///".*                 printf("comment %s\n", yytext);
[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*  printf("symbol %s\n", yytext);
```

Similarly, as for `bison` code, I recommend first resolving grammatical
issue like shift/reduce-conflict, and confirming that the grammar is
recognized properly with simple code like:

```
commented_variable: IDENTIFIER NAME COMMENT { puts("OK"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're actually *using* the text following the delimiter, I would *not* use the word "comment" for anything you have above. That said, what you've put into your update is pretty much the right idea.

Comment: could you explain this further?  I'm not really sure what you mean.